# What does (10 hours)² mean? (specifications)

Tags: battery

I was looking at the [specifications of the MacBooks (pro)](http://store.apple.com/uk/buy-mac/macbook-pro) on Apples website and I saw this. *Built-in battery (10 hours)²*.

What does the '²' mean? Why (10 hours)² and not 10 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an explanation in the footnotes:

> 2 Testing conducted by Apple in February 2015 using pre-production 2.9GHz dual-      core Intel Core i5–based 13-inch MacBook Pro units. The wireless web test measures battery life by wirelessly browsing 25 popular websites with display brightness set to 12 clicks from bottom or 75%. The HD film playback test measures battery life by playing back HD 1080p content with display brightness set to 12 clicks from bottom or 75%. Battery life varies by use and configuration. See www.apple.com/uk/batteries for more information.

Comment: Exactly. It is referring to the footnote.

Answer (score 2):

‘²’ indicates there’s a footnote. It means, see the second footnote. It doesn’t mean the battery life is 10² hours, though that would be awesome.

Comment: I knew it didn't mean 10² hours. :)